# Session time out not firing when using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, signalr

**EDIT**

I'm using SignalR 1.2.2 in .NET 4.0. In this version, is it true that every call in server will update session time-out? Including Ping for every 5 minutes and Long polling.

- If it is true, is there any workaround to not update the session timeout using version 1.2.2 in .NET 4.0?

I also noticed that in latest version 2.2.0, SignalR calls(PING) are not updating session time-out.

Comment: So just to check, you _want_ your session to time out? It's a bit complicated because, unless you use WebSockets, any SignalR call-to-the-server, will update the session cookie's timeout.

If it's all server-side pushes, then disabling pings will cause the session to timeout.

Comment: Yes, I want SignalR to not update session timeout for every calls. See for my update, thanks.